# Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>), at window.onload

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, json, typescript

```
// Text write
var TxtType = function (el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = "";
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = !1;
};
TxtType.prototype.tick = function () {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];
    if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + "</span>";
    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;
    if (this.isDeleting) {
        delta /= 2;
    }
    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = !0;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === "") {
        this.isDeleting = !1;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        that.tick();
    }, delta);
};
window.onload = function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("typewrite");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute("data-type");
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute("data-period");
        if (toRotate) {
            new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.txt = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

i'm making this javascript typewriting effect using json and css with 3 elements in it
 `<a class="typewrite color-linear" href="/" data-period="3000"  data-type="["Dhruv Verma", "Designer", "Creator"]"></a>`
but i'm constanty getting this error, which says json ended unexpectedly, i dont know what exactly it means please help, frequent help will be appriciated

Comment: the json in that data-type attribute would be formally correct and would work passed as is to JSON.parse. Maybe there's a content not shown here that doesn't? Consider also that the double quotes would be escaped and as shown in the question it wouldn't be valid html. Maybe try to console.log(toRotate) before performing the parse so you'll know what's the latest content failing

Comment: `<a class="typewrite color-linear" href="/" data-period="3000"  data-type="["Dhruv Verma", "Designer", "Creator"]"></a>` is not valid HTML and `data-type` will be the string `"["`. If you try to parse that, it will throw the error you mentioned. You can use single quotes instead: `data-type='["Dhruv Verma", "Designer", "Creator"]'`.